# PDF Pages to Images Using Imagick Skips Last PDF Page

Tags: php, image, pdf, imagick

I am using Imagick to generate JPG images from a pre-generated PDF file which contains several pages, Eg file contains a total of 6 pages as PDF File. After running through the code below as:

```
        $imagick = new \Imagick();
        $imagick->setResolution(500, 500);
        $imagick->readImage($pdfFinalFile);
        $imagick->writeImages($jpgPath.'/Image.jpg',false);
```

Output comes total of 5 JPG images from 0 to 4 numbered sequences.

Unable to determine why `writeImages` function is skipping the Last Page of PDF which I have determined by checking the details on the Image that the Last Page is skipped

- Version: ImageMagick-6
- PHP Version: 7.1
- OS: Ubuntu 18

Expecting all the Pages of the PDF should be converted to Images

Comment: Post a link to your PDF file and I will check it with the command line to export to JPG to see if I get only 5 pages. What is the exact version of ImageMagick 6.x.x.x?

Comment: https://files.fm/down.php?cf&i=sqeypm9t&n=ProcessedFile_1566367803.pdf

Not on dev machine  now will update you exact version

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 @fmw42

Comment: I get 6 pages (0 to 5) when convert on IM 6.9.10.61 Q16 Mac OSX. I suspect it is the version of Ghostscript in your install that may be the issue. I am using GS 9.2.5. You may be using a very old version since your version of ImageMagick is ancient (2.5 years old according to the date). You might check for an updated patch on your Linux system. Or simply upgrade Ghostscript. Type `gs --version` in a terminal window and it will tell you your version

Comment: Updated the GS script and ImageMagick to the latest version and it works like a charm, Thanks for the help @fmw42

Answer (score 0):

try this code I not near to computer

```
$im = new Imagick();

$im->setResolution(3000,3000);
$im->readimage('file.pdf'); 
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');    
$im->writeImage('outb.jpg'); 
$im->clear(); 
$im->destroy();
```

Comment: This will only provide me with one image